# Is random walk with drift is random?

Tags: autocorrelation, trend, lags, random-walk, randomness

I see everywhere in the web that lag-plot or acf are used to see if a time serie is random. If there is no structure in the lag plot then the data are random, and if autocorrelation = 0 then data is random.

But the lag-plot for a random walk with drift is a line and the acf is decreasing very slowly to 0 (because yt is related to yt-1 )... So can you explain me what happen here ?

Thanks you very much !

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DATA IS RANDOM PART OF YOUR QUESTION:

As Matt said, a random walk process is perfectly autocorrelated. But you're correct in that, if the  autocorrelations in the acf are ( statistically ) zero everywhere, then tbis implies that the data are random. Matt makes a good point also  that the data are random is not a good usage and it's better to say that the data points are independent of each other. If you make the additional assumption that they are identically distributed, then people usually use "data are iid" rather than "data are random".

You might be saying that the rw is representative of the data being random because, in finance, if the log price is an RW, then people says that prices are perfectly random and can't be predicted. But they really are saying is that the best prediction for tomorrow is today's prediction which is, technically speaking, not saying that the data is random. That "data is random" concept is more a terminology that comes out of the efficient markets community in finance.

TESTING PART OF YOUR QUESTION:

Note that, when testing is the a series is iid, you have to take out the drift first and then check the acf. The acf makes the assumption that the mean is constant and with a drift, you don't have constant mean so you have de-trend and then look at the acf.

Note through that a series can be difference stationary or trend stationary so the method for taking out the drift depends on what it is.  If you sure that it's difference stationary ( which is a randon walk with drift is ), you can take it out by differencing. If not, there's a whole literature on trend stationary versus difference stationary that you can look at.

ADDENDUM:

Note that if you had an RW without drift: $x_t = x_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$

and you differenced it: $x_t - x_{t-1} = \epsilon_t$.

Then, the differenced series, $x_t - x_{t-1} = \epsilon_t$ can be considered iid or using the other terminology,  "random".

Note that to make the connection to finance, if $x_t$ in the above is the log price, then that implies that the log returns are random which is the theory efficient markets people in finance support.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think you're misunderstanding a couple things here:

1. Lag and ACF plots don't show if a time series is "random" but instead show significant autocorrelations.
2. Random walks are autocorrelated by definition, since in a random walk, `x_t+1 = x_t + e` where `e ~ N(0, sig)`. This means that my best guess for the next value in the series is the current value in the series, up to some random noise.
3. I'm still not sure if I understand what you mean by "the data are random" here